# Script en Linux para buscar archivos de un tipo especifico

Tags: linux, script

tengo que hacer un script en linux que me pide lo siguiente:
realizar un script de bash que almacene en un archivo todos los programas de un directorio cuyo path absoluto se pasa como parámetro y cuyo nombre termine en una extensión también pasada como parámetro y sobre los cuales el usuario que ejecuta el script tiene permiso de ejecución.

yo hice lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

deltipo=`find $1 -name "*.$2"`

for i in `ls -la $deltipo`; do

if [ $i -x ]; do

$i>>programasQuePuedoEjecutar

fi

done
```

podría controlar antes el numero de parámetros y hacerlo mas prolijo, pero nose si la forma en que lo resolví es correcta o si hay alguna forma mas directa de hacerlo.
gracias x las rtas!!

Comment: ¿Conoces el comando "grep"?

Comment: si lo conozco, pero eso analiza todo el archivo, seria similar usar find y grep mientras que lo guarde en algún lado para poder ir preguntando por cada archivo que coincidió si es ejecutable o no.

Comment: esto te ayudará: find $directory -type f -name "*.in"

Comment: pero si pones el -type ya no hace falta poner el nombre? puede pasar que tenga una extensión pero es de un tipo distinto. y ese find me daría todos los resultados, después tendría que recorrerlo de nuevo para ver cuales son los ejecutables y guardarlos en otro archivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede no ser un script, sino un one liner.

```
$ find /ruta/de/directorio/ -type f -name "*.extension" -executable >> programasQuePuedoEjecutar
```

En este caso, `find` utiliza los parámetros `-type` para saber si es un archivo `f`, porque puede ser de otro tipo: socket `s`, directorio `d`, pipe `p`, door `D`, caracter `c`, enlace simbólico `l`, de bloque `b`.

Además de que utiliza el parámetro `-name` para buscar sobre la extensión de un archivo. Por ejemplo `"*.pdf"`, osea, todos los archivos con extensión de pdf.

Y, por último, utiliza el parámetro `-executable` para listar los archivos que tienen permisos de ejecución por el usuario, pero puedes cambiarlo por estos dos parámetros extras

```
-perm /u+x -user nombre_del_usuario
```

el cual busca que los tenga permisos de ejecución por parte del usuario y que dicho usuario sea al que le pertenece el archivo.

Por ejemplo, si tienes un directorio de esta forma.

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 yo       yo       512 Feb  1 14:48 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 yo       yo       512 Feb  1 14:31 ..
-rwxrw-rw- 1 yo       yo         0 Feb  1 14:31 archivo1.ext
-rw-rw-rw- 1 usuario1 usuario1   0 Feb  1 14:31 archivo2.ext
-rwxrw-rw- 1 usuario1 usuario1   0 Feb  1 14:31 archivo3.ext
-rw-rw-rw- 1 usuario1 usuario1   0 Feb  1 14:31 archivo4.ext
-rwxrw-rw- 1 yo       yo         0 Feb  1 14:31 archivo5.ext

$ find . -type f -name "*.ext" -executable
./archivo1.ext
./archivo5.ext

$ find . -type f -name "*.ext" -user yo -perm /u+x
./archivo1.ext
./archivo5.ext
```

Y ya no haces un script, sino que pasas directamente la extensión y el nombre de la carpeta.

Que también lo podrías hacer con variables, por ejemplo, poner la variable `RUTA=/tu/ruta` y `EXTENSION=pdf`.

Y pones eso en el one liner, de la forma:

```
$ find $RUTA -type f -name "*.$EXTENSION" -executable
```

Y únicamente varías el contenido de las variables RUTA y EXTENSION.

Comment: genial! lo entendí, sabia que había una forma mas sencilla de hacerlo. Gracias!

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido. Me apoyarías (emocionalmente) al ponerla como válida (si es que fue la respuesta que te sirvió) o añadiéndole un voto a favor.